# How to mount a component that uses vue3-markdown-it with vue-test-utils?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, markdown, vue-test-utils, vitest

I'm trying to implement a unit test (using `vitest` and `vue-test-utils`) of a component that internally uses the `Markdown` component from [vue3-markdown-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-markdown-it)

This is a minimal example:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { test, expect } from 'vitest'
import Markdown from 'vue3-markdown-it'

const Component = {
  template: '<div><Markdown source="text markdown"/></div>',
  components: {
    Markdown
  }
}

test('Component with Markdown ', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Component, {
    global: {
      components: { Markdown }
    }
  })

  expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('text markdown')
})
```

The test fails with the following output:

```bash
stderr | test/unit/pages/TestComponent.spec.js > Component with Markdown 
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function.

FAIL  test/unit/pages/TestComponent.spec.js > Component with Markdown 
AssertionError: expected '<div>\n  <!---->\n</div>' to include 'text markdown'
```

From the error, I see that it fails to mount the `Markdown` component.

Why does it fails to mount the `Markdown` component in such test, but the component renders correctly in my Vue app?